# Depositing or cashing a $2 Million check

Tags: banking, central-bank

I would like to ask you the question. Will 2 millions dollars check to be cash? and How long will 2 millions dollars check to be cash?

I understand, but the 2 millions dollars check from the headquarter company that was paid to the anonymous worker at boutique and he wants to cash the check.  I was not sure how it works.  If the bank couldn't cash for him, will the bank give him some of cash for example, $500,000 for now, and the rest wait to be cash at later time like 24 hours or 1 week?  Sorry for confusion.  Thanks!

Comment: I understand the down votes and the close votes, but note I think this question is on-topic here, albeit not particularly clearly. This sort of question comes up if you get an insurance payout or if you are being scammed. Both of which are directly relevant to personal finance.

Comment: @Carolyn - it would be great if you'd add a country tag, and a bit more background like why someone got the check for this amount.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - agreed. There are stacks whose terms specifically request that members do not vote to close for "unclear" until 24 hours after request for clarification. From [tex.se](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) "Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close."  Here, I've suggested the 24 hr rule, as it would stand to reason some have a time they are on the net each day.

Comment: Are you asking to deposit the check into an account or to have the check converted to cash? The bank will generally have no problem depositing a check of just about any size. The issue with converting it to cash is that they may not have the cash on hand. For larger cash withdrawals (not THAT large, though) I've usually given my bank a day or two notice (or ask them to state a day).

Comment: If you are asking because someone told you they received a check for $2 million, and they can't cash it themselves for some reason, and they want you to help them do it: **Run away, this is a scam.**

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing particularly special about a two million dollar cheque. While they aren't commonplace, the bank certainly has experience with them. Many ATMs won't allow a deposit of that size but the bank cashiers will certainly accept them. They will typically get a supervisor to sign off on the deposit and may ask about the source of the money, for fraud prevention reasons.

They may be held for longer than a smaller cheque if the bank manager chooses to do so. If there's nothing remotely suspicious (for example, it is a cheque from an insurance company for an expected payout), you should expect it will clear in about a week. On the other hand, if it is a cheque from a bank in another country and the bank manager has any reason to suspect it may not be legitimate, they may hold it for a month or more. Even then, you are not guaranteed the cheque was legitimate. This is used in a common scam.

Answer (score 7):

Careful, this could be a scam.  But if not.... There is no feasible way to turn that into cash without a **very** good reason that will require your banker to know you, as a depositor, reasonably well.  And it sounds like you aren't banked at all.

If this is *your* money, please pay attention - Class in America is defined by financial knowledge.  If you are unbanked and lower class, $2M is actually *dangerous* - read a book called "Money for Nothing" about what happens to lottery winners.  Honestly the tendency is for lower-class people to be *possessed* to keep making lower-class financial decisions, which directly lead them to be broke and bankrupt in months regardless of the size of the windfall. So making decisions differently is *literally rehab*... No exaggeration.  To change your thinking, you'll want to read Suze Orman, John Bogle and Napoleon Hill.  For an American who thinks about money the way the upper-middle-class does, $2M in the bank means the end of the 9-5 grind. He will still need to work, but will be able to be much more selective about choosing jobs which are fulfilling.  It brings him the utopia we were promised.

If you are currently unbanked, you will simply need to *get* banked to handle a check of this size.   Handling this much cash is literally impossible due to the RICO laws designed to stop drug dealing and money laundering.  Even if you split it into many small amounts, that itself is **structuring** which is a felony *all its own*.

So let's get banked.   A $2M check is a terrible entré into the banking world because it makes you smell like a criminal or scammer at first introduction.  I could deposit one no problem because I have 10 years of history with my bank.  But you, you'll need to convince the bank you're the real deal, and give them reason to trust you. Be prepared to that "trust" to include depositing some money... at the least, the bank will want to know you're good for the bad-check fees they suspect will follow.

Go to a local bank or savings-and-loan that you trust, the smaller the better, and sit down with a banker.  Describe your situation honestly and have him open an account and deposit the check.  If your burned your ability to open checking accounts with a ChexSystems mark, you'll need to be more selective about banks and be honest about that to the banker.  And wait a month for that check to clear positively, believe me your banker will be watching that.

At that point, if you want great bunches of the money out quickly, it'll need to be in the form of a cheque or bank check.  Cash ain't gonna happen, nor should it.  The reason is, again, the RICO laws.

Of course, if you are a criminal or scam victim, none of the above applies, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> Will 2 millions dollars check to be cash?

Will a bank convert a check to cash?  In my experience, no.  Even for small checks.   Unless you happen to have a VERY good relationship with your banker (read as: have an existing large bank balance.)   The exception is if you go to the bank the check is drawn on.   But even then, I doubt they'll cash a $2M dollar check.

Can you deposit a $2M dollar check?  Most definitely.

> How long will 2 millions dollars check to be cash?

Depends on your bank's policies, relationship with you, and the origination of the check.  You'll need to talk to the exact bank in question to find out.  Some guidelines from my own experiences: Out of country checks will take quite awhile, say 4 weeks, even for trivial amounts.  I'm not sure what a $2M size would do.   Beyond that situation, it will likely depend on whether you have more money than the check's worth in your bank accounts.  If so, they may be willing to give you cash in a few days.  Or if you only want some of the money as cash in a few days, that might be possible.

> If the bank couldn't cash for him, will the bank give him some of cash
>   for example, $500,000 for now, and the rest wait to be cash at later
>   time like 24 hours or 1 week?

Unless you already have a lot of money in your relationship with the bank, I think it is HIGHLY UNLIKELY they will let you have ANY of the money in 24 hours.  You MIGHT get some of it in a week.   The issue will be that such a large check will be viewed as having a high chance of being fraudulent, so they will want to be exceptionally conservative.

Comment: My understanding is that there are regulations about how long a bank can hold onto a check. Banks can't just decide to be more conservative in a given situation. (Some scammers have used this to their advantage by setting up a check that takes longer than that number of days to be discovered as fraudulent.)  Is the $2m check an exception to the rule, due to its size and/or origin?

Comment: The OP hasn't tagged the question for a specific country.  So while some countries may have regulations (for example the US has Regulation CC) not all do.  If you read Reg CC, you'll note that it gives timeframes for <$5,000 amounts, but for >$5,000 the bank is allowed (section 229.13h) to delay availability for a "reasonable" timeframe.  "Reasonable" has some guidance but as long as it can show a timeframe was "reasonable", then it has leeway.  You'll note that the reason why it can exceed the smaller $ timeframes is to reduce risk, as I imply above.

Comment: Also in Reg CC, the scope of which checks the defined timeframes apply to is defined as "local" checks.  Thus the origin of the check may definitely be an exception.

Comment: @stannus Checks to open accounts (no pre-existing relationship) have much longer hold times, as does a check the bank has positive reasons to believe may be bogus. (USA rules.) There may be some small (as in $100) amount that must be available for immediate use, but nothing close to $2 million.